# How to add a dynamic id into a loader in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I decided to load the images first then, draw it unto the canvas.

I want to add a button to allow the image to be moved around. For that I need the ID of the image. Does the image have an ID or can I give the image an id?

I want to be able to change the ID of the image with a loop. For example, everything in a certain area of the canvas becomes pit1marble1, pit1marble2.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="479" usemap="Canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var sources = {
        background: 'MANCALA-game_bg_combined3.png',


      };

      loadImages(sources, function(images) {
        context.drawImage(images.background, 0, 0, 1024, 479);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cut away the obscuring words to try and find a question.

Comment: i think, content inside a canvas isn't part of the DOM, so you need a solution for your own to manage the canvas content...

Comment: No, canvas drawings do not have id's nor are they individually recognizable. You will have to keep track of each image you draw -- probably in an array of objects representing your "drawn" images: {id:1, x:10, y:25, width:50, height:35}. Then on mousedown you must hit-test each object in the array to discover if the mouse is over any particular image. Here is Documentation on how to [hit-test rectangles](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5017/collisions-and-intersections/17716/is-an-x-y-point-inside-a-rectangle#t=201611151717464411316).